# How to put my OneNote notes from my machine to onedrive?

Tags: sync, microsoft-onenote

I have several notes on my OneNote on mac. I accidentally deleted the OneNote file on my OneDrive.
I have a copy of the notes on my mac but It is, understandably not able to synch with the server because the file is not there on the server.
**How do I put the notes I have on my mac on the server?**

Answer (score 0):

After trying various options, this is what worked for me. It is not exactly what i was looking for but i was able to save my notes.
I used the OneNote 2016 (not the free one) to export all my sections to files.
***Note: You cannot do this for the whole notebook, fortunately you can export whole sections.(small mercies).***
These show up as 'Open Sections'. Once I had exported all my sections. I copied them one by one from the 'Open Sections' to another notebook. I synched this notebook and that was it.